# Visual Studio 2015 hangs when I open the Package Manager Console

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

The panel appears and it says "Package Manager Console Host version 3.2.0.10515" and "Initializing PowerShell host..." It stays like this and I have to shut down VS using the Task Manager.

Comment: Hey @John-H, did you manage to fix this? I've got almost the same version - 3.2.0.10516 and precisely the same symptoms.. Gragh!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has published a hotfix for that issue, here is information how to apply it:

Here is the [Link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1572078/nuget-crash-in-visual-studio-2015-enterprise)

Or This command line can be used to automate the process (run as admin), until issue is fixed:

```
reg delete HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell /v ExecutionPolicy /f
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559268/nuget-crash-in-visual-studio-2015/31560200#31560200)

Comment: This didn't work. I have NuGet Package Manager version 3.2.6, which is newer than the hotfix. I don't have the PowerShell registry path. I am using Windows 10 and also had the same problem in Windows 7.

Comment: @JohnH Check this [link](http://blog.jsinh.in/nuget-install-update-error-failed-to-initialize-the-powershell-host/#.Vg1kbeyqqko)